# RCLONE : Invalid 'access_token' with pCloud

Tags: linux, shell, userscripts, rclone, pcloud

I'm trying to use rclone with pCloud storage service.
I have folowed these steps:

- https://rclone.org/pcloud/
- https://rclone.org/remote_setup/

The configuration file looks this at the end of the process:

```
[remote]
type = pcloud
token = {"access_token":"MY_ACCESS_TOKEN","token_type":"bearer","expiry":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"}
```

But when I launch this command:

```
rclone ls remote:/
```

I get this error:

> 2020/10/10 17:23:22 ERROR : : error listing: couldn't list files:
> pcloud error: Invalid 'access_token' provided. (2094) 2020/10/10
> 17:23:22 Failed to ls with 2 errors: last error was: couldn't list
> files: pcloud error: Invalid 'access_token' provided. (2094)

I don't understand why because everything was fine during the configuration steps.

I did the same config with DROPBOX and GOOGLE DRIVE and works fine.
But failed with PCLOUD.

If you have an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution found.
so for info, from EU, here is a correct conf file :

```
[remote]
type = pcloud
hostname = eapi.pcloud.com
token = {"access_token":"TOKEN","token_type":"bearer","expiry":"0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"}
```